# SQL Server Profiler with .NET call stack

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, debugging, sql-server-profiler

Are there any tools out there that offer the ability to profile a SQL Server instance (like "SQL Server Profiler") but with the added benefit of providing a .NET call stack?

So, it would likely have to be running a profiler session on the SQL instance while simultaneously running the .NET app through a debugger and somehow linking up the database calls to events within the application.

Perhaps even a way in VS, SqlProfiler, or SSMS that I'm just unaware of...?

Is a feature like this even feasible?

Thank you

Comment: Miniprofiler, configured for EF or ADO.NET. It can be used with console applications as well.

Comment: BTW the question is kind of backwards - you can't know the client's call stack once you reach the server. You *can* log the queries executed by ADO.NET, EF or any other ORM along with the call stack using a *lot* of tools.

Comment: App Insights as well. Glimpse for ASP.NET web apps, although it isn't maintained any more. What kind of application are you building?

Comment: Visual Studio itself, with its Intellitrace Events

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think this is helpful.  I'm aware of Intellitrace (although I guess it slipped my mind in this case)... perhaps that's a more logical place to start.  To @PanagiotisKanavos 's second comment, I guess that's what I meant when I asked if it was feasible.  At least without doing some hacky assumptive mapping between the SQL server and your code... Part of this question related to an issue I'm working on, part of it was just based out of pure curiosity. i.e., the feasibility of pinpointing code while debugging from the end of the chain of events (SQL Server).

Comment: This one in particular is Web API.... Automapper with EF, trying to figure out exactly what is locking a record from me accessing it.  I have an Address record with a State associated, the StateID is set and everything, but when I save it, it adds a NEW state with a new State ID.  It's a problem I've solved in the past, but it's always kind of a pain to do...  If I call DbCOntext.Attach it errors out saying the record is already in use.

Comment: SQL Server is a *different* system. It doesn't know anything about the systems that call it. You can specify an Application name in the connection string if you want, which will appear as an attribute in any trace.

Comment: Then it's easy - use MiniProfiler, AppInsights or any other similar system. You can store their output to SQL Server if you want, for cross-reference. I also use StackExchange's Exceptional to keep track of exceptions, with SQL Server for storage

Comment: As for `what is locking a record from me accessing it.` most likely a long-running transaction, like the horrible antipattern that opens a transaction for the duration of a request. What for? `SaveChanges` uses a transaction already! Most often that happens when people mistakenly try to implement Unit-Of-Work by using transactions.

Comment: You can find which *query* blocks another if you open Activity Monitor in SSMS and check the `Blocked By` column. That shows the connection ID that blocks your query. You see what query is executed by each connection in Activity Monitor itself by right clicking on it